# Authority-check with ACTVT = 01 or 02

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I need to check if ACTVT is 01 or 02, WERKS from selection screen, DIRCT – Y and VD from range A, B, C, K, R, O. The code below didn't check for this letters, in test i could select any, not only selected into lv_values as it was expected. Any advice where to look at, or may be there's another solution?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'Z_GET_PARAMS'
      EXPORTING
        iv_repid        = 'ZMM_LIM'
        iv_param        = 'VD'
     IMPORTING
       et_values       = lt_values.

    LOOP AT lt_values ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lf_values>).

* Проверка прав
      AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'ZMM_LIMIT'
             ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '01'
             ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '02'
             ID 'WERKS' FIELD s_werks
             ID 'DIRCT' FIELD 'Y'
             ID 'VD' FIELD <lf_values>-low
```

Comment: More information is needed. Can you include in your post all your code please? If it possible include a screenshot of transaction 'SU21' with the authorization object 'ZMM_LIMIT'.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't have the same field multiple times in a single `AUTHORITY-CHECK` statement - you'll have to do the `OR` for yourself. I wouldn't be surprised if you got `sy-subrc = 24`, indicating a programming error rather than a missing authority.

Comment: It's not even starting in current form. Correct me, but it looks like authority check didn't allow 'or' statement? Should i made two different checks, separated by some IF statement?

Comment: @AlexanderK Exactly.